# Keyword search in string

Tags: python, string, list

I'm making simple keyword recognition program where I have a `txt` file and every word is in new line. I open as a list and then I check for every keyword in sentence I will later open from database.

So far I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

I get it both needs to be string-string or list-list. I experimented and tried to convert the sentence into list - program returned nothing.

Any suggestions how to make this work, or suggestions how to change things to make it correct?

```
results = []
with open('words.txt') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        results.append(line.strip())


#print results

all_text = 'vistumšākā zaudēt zilumi nāve'

#all_texts = all_text.split()

for word in results:
    if results in all_texts:
        x += 1

print x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a simple typo here. You're trying to check each `word` from your `words.txt` file, but you're using `results` in your `if` statement. Hence the error; Python's saying "I expected this variable to contain a string, but it was actually a list." Change your second `for` loop:

```
for word in results:
    if word in all_texts:
        x += 1
```

I've renamed your variables to be more descriptive in the full program below:

```
word_list = []
with open('words.txt') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        word_list.append(line.strip())

source_text = 'vistumšākā zaudēt zilumi nāve'
source_words = source_text.split()
count = 0    

for word in word_list:
    if word in source_words:
        count += 1

print count
```